# how to group the same or similar pixels in an image

Tags: python, opencv

How can I group the pixels with the same intensity or similar intensity in opencv Python. I am asked to find these pixels and connect the disconnected pixels with same intensities.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com! Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [M.C.V E](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your post answerable. In short you are missing code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a **blob detector** (eg, `cv2.SimpleBlobDetector`), though there are other approaches as well.  [Here's](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/) a post on how to do blog detection in OpenCV.  As described in the post, "A Blob is a group of connected pixels in an image that share some common property ( E.g grayscale value )," which seems like what you want.